# New instance every time using NavigationPage in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Let's say i have 3 Xaml views and i use a MasterDetailPage and NavigationPage to navigate back and forward to those pages. Page A -> Page B -> Page C -> ...

I use PushAsync to perform the navigation. No big deal...

I implemment that in two ways:

**1 -** Create a new instance of those views every time on navigation:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.PageA());
```

**2 -** Create a static property (at App view) for each page and i use that for navigation:

```
public static Views.PageA PageA 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pageA == null)
            {
                _pageA = new Views.PageA();
            }

            return _pageA =;
        }
    }


await Navigation.PushAsync(App.PageA);
```

**Is there another way to do that? Use static or new instance every time?**

My concern it's about performance and memmory usage.

Please let's your answear with your opinion and some code will be apreciated.

Comment: Are you testing it on `Android`?

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad in both iOS and Adroid simulators and devices

Comment: I don't if it happens in both `iOS` and `Android` but Android  `Activity`s will always get re-created. One of the workarounds is `Singleton`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use push and pop. you can use pushmodalasync to create new root page (navigation stack count = 1 in this case). and poptorootasync to turn back to your root page(navigationstack[0]).

Comment: And yes i would recommand creating new page each time as with some constructors..

Comment: do you know how to mensure that?

Comment: I dont know how you can test the performance but i do it this way and never had problem.. Static values can be annoying because you have to be careful with your values..